# Blazor NavigationManager NullReference error in code behind

Tags: blazor

Using Blazor in VS19 Professional I'm getting a NullReference exception when I try to use the NavigationManager.NavigateTo function from the code behind .razor.cs file.

I first inject the NaviagtionManager at the top of the .razor.cs file:

```
[Inject]
protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
```

Then when the users clicks a submit button, data is saved to an SQL database (this part works fine) and then the page should then redirect to another page, but it fails due to ***"NavigationManager.get returned null"*** error.

This is the function saving the data and calling the NavigationManager:

```
public void Update() {

        participants p = new participants {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(id),
            FirstName = participant[0].FirstName,
            LastName = participant[0].LastName,
            Eating = participant[0].Eating,
            Bowling = participant[0].Bowling,
            EscapeRoom = participant[0].EscapeRoom
        };

        this.Db.UpdateParticipant(p);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Bowling/2020");
    }
```

I have been unable to find anything online to help me with this issue.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this??

UPDATE WITH MORE CODE:

On the .razor page I have an EditForm which on submit calls an Update():

```
<EditForm Model="@participant" OnValidSubmit="@Update">
```

On the .razor.cs page, this is the Update() function:

```
public void Update() {

        participants p = new participants {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(id),
            FirstName = participant[0].FirstName,
            LastName = participant[0].LastName,
            Eating = participant[0].Eating,
            Bowling = participant[0].Bowling,
            EscapeRoom = participant[0].EscapeRoom
        };

        this.Db.UpdateParticipant(p);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Bowling/2020/");
    }
```

The values in the database get updated correctly.

UPDATE:

Found the issue, see response below.

Comment: Is your *.razor.cs* a partial class ?

Comment: It is not. I have declared it like this:
**public class UpdateParticipantBase : ComponentBase {**

Comment: Did you try to declare your `NavigationManager` property public ?

Comment: I did not. I declared it as protected. Changing it to a public property didn't change anything.

Comment: How do you use this class ? A razor component derived from it ? Post the code please.

Comment: I have updated my question with more code

Comment: So you declare again an `Update` function on the razor component with the same code ? I don't get why you do, actually. Why do you have a base class if you don't use its methods ?

Comment: I guess you probably forgot an `@inherits UpdateParticipantBase`in your *.razor*

Comment: I do have the @inherits UpdateParticipantBase in the .razor file

Comment: I found out what the issue was - I will update my question.

Answer (score 2):

This was a clear case of "don't leave anything out of your code example".

In my code I had this:

```
[Inject]
protected BowlingData Db { get; set; }
protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
```

(Being new to Blazor, I figured that the [Inject] would include everything following it until my [Parameters] just under this code snip.

When I posted the question, I removed the

```
protected BowlingData Db {get; set;}
```

line to minimize the amount of example code. If I hadn't done that, I'm sure my question would have been answered right away.

As soon as I added the second [inject] my code worked as it should:

```
[Inject]
protected BowlingData Db { get; set; }
[Inject]
protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
```

Lessoned learned - both about Blazor and about posting questions :)